# LightSwitch Model Loading Failed in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created Views in SQL Server and Added that view in Visual Studio LightSwitch 2015 and Build is successful locally.

I am getting Build Errors for that view in VSTS

Below is the attached error for this. Could not find any clue on this.

[LightSwitch Model Loading Failed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoA9u.jpg)

Comment: adding solution to source control usually breaks it to unrecoverable state

Comment: Thanks you got my point.